# keyDown handler being fired twice instead of once in custom React hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-listener, keydown

I have the following hook:

```
export default function useKeyPress(targetKey: string) {
    const [keyPressed, setKeyPressed] = useState(false);
    

    const downHandler = (e) => {
        if (e.repeat) {
            return;
        }

        if (e.key === targetKey) {
            console.log(targetKey);
            setKeyPressed(true);
        }
    }
    
    const upHandler = ({ key }) => {
        if (key === targetKey) {
            setKeyPressed(false);
        }
    }

    
    useEffect(() => {
        if (window !== undefined) {
            window.addEventListener('keydown', downHandler);
            window.addEventListener('keyup', upHandler);
        }
        return () => {
            if (window !== undefined) {
                window.removeEventListener('keydown', downHandler)
                window.removeEventListener('keyup', upHandler)
            }
    }
  }, []) 

    return keyPressed;
}
```

The console.log(targetKey) always returns the result twice. I.e if I hit V, it will console log it twice.

I am trying to implement a function call in my React component that calls a function once control + v is hit. But the issue is that it calls it twice, thus not following specification.

I've tried using useState booleans to intercept a second call but it hasn't worked.

I use it in the following manner:

```
    const pressedControl = useKeyPress('Control');
    const pressedV = useKeyPress('v');

useEffect(() => {
    if (pressedControl && pressedV) {
        console.log("Ctrl + V");
    }


}, [pressedC, pressedV]);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `e.preventDefault()` on the first line within your `downHandler` function?

Comment: I would think it runs your event twice because you're listening to `keydown` and `keyup` which fires both when someone clicks a key ... also you're adding your events twice for both `control` and `v` keys

Comment: I checked with only 1 instance of a hook called "pressedA". The down handler is fired twice, and so is the up handler.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it was being fired twice was because I set up the hooks inside a component that is created in a map function which iterates an array of objects. In this case, I had 2 objects, meaning it fired twice for each. I'm moving the logic to a parent component.